# HTTPMethod for patch, put and delete don't work, 400 Status code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

In my controller I have several endpoints for update, delete and create.

- HTTPPost works for all environments (local, staging, and production)
- patch, put and delete work on **local and staging** but don't work in **production**

Here are my endpoints:

```
    [Authorize(Policy = "user_role")]
    public class TestController : BaseApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateTestAsync(CreateTestDTO request)
        {
            //code deleted for brevity
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteTestAsync(Guid schedulerID)
        {
             //code deleted for brevity
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateTestAsync(UpdateTestDTO request)
        {
            //code deleted for brevity
        }

        [HttpPatch]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ToggleTestAsync(Guid schedulerID, bool active)
        {
            //code deleted for brevity
        }
     }
```

By using postman I can update, delete, create in local and staging environments but when I change the environment to Production I get 400 status code for HttpDelete, HttpPut and HttpPatch.

As I said, HttpPost works in all environments.

Example on production:
[image]

Comment: "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" looks like you have some policy on prod that refuses some verbs from outside the local network. Try maybe taking it up with your devops team

Comment: Well, the error message "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" indicates that your browser is enforcing the Same-Origin Policy, and there might be a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) problem with your request configuration. Have you  checked the detailed logging in your production environment to capture more information about the request and response. This can help identify the specific issue. Apart from that, make sure your production server is configured to allow requests from the domain where your front-end is hosted or the place where your request is coming from.

Comment: Oh, one more thing, For PUT, DELETE, and PATCH, the browser might send a preflight request (OPTIONS) to check if the server allows the actual request.  Therefore, also check that your server handles these preflight requests correctly